# Java inheritance issue

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I am having an issue with my program that should return this output:

```
  Portfolio #00001, ASD = 42.50, DFAS = 45.00, CAC = 22.20, BDM = 52.50
  Portfolio #00002, ASD = 42.50, DFAS = 45.00, CAC = 22.20, BDM = 52.50
  Portfolio #00001, ASD = 43.35, DFAS = 45.90, CAC = 22.64, BDM = 53.55
  Portfolio #00002, ASD = 43.35, DFAS = 45.90, CAC = 22.64, BDM = 53.55
  Portfolio #00001, ASD = 41.18, DFAS = 43.61, CAC = 21.51, BDM = 50.87
  Portfolio #00002, ASD = 41.18, DFAS = 43.61, CAC = 21.51, BDM = 50.87
  Portfolio #00001, ASD = 43.65, DFAS = 46.22, CAC = 22.80, BDM = 53.92
  Portfolio #00002, ASD = 43.65, DFAS = 46.22, CAC = 22.80, BDM = 53.92
```

Currently, my program is not returning anything. Could someone please help?

Here are the classes :

DisplayElement Interface :

```
public interface DisplayElement {
    public void display();
}
```

Observer Interface :

```
public interface Observer {
    public void update (Map<String,Double> priceMap);
}
```

Comment: try firstPortfolio.display() in your main

Comment: setPrices(map PriceMap) does not set anything.

Comment: You need to register your Portfolios to enable the pattern

Comment: Im not sure exactly what i should set in the setPrices(map PriceMap) method

Comment: try the code in my post, it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your protfolios after their creation, and before calling setPrices(), as required by the observer pattern: Your program should be like :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


 interface DisplayElement {
     void display();
}

 interface Observer {
     void update (Map<String,Double> priceMap);
}


 class PricesDisplay implements Observer, DisplayElement {
    private String ticker;
    private double price;
    private Subject PriceData;
    Map<String,Double> priceMap;


      PricesDisplay(Subject PriceData) {
        this.PriceData = PriceData;
    }

PricesDisplay(String ticker, Subject PriceData) {
    this.ticker = ticker;
    this.PriceData = PriceData;
}

public void update(Map<String,Double> priceMap) {
    this.priceMap = priceMap;
    display();
}

public void display() {
     for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : priceMap.entrySet()) {
         System.out.printf("\nPortfolio #%s, " + "%s = " + "%.2f, ",
         ticker, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
         }
}
}



interface Subject{
    void registerObserver(Observer o);
    void removeObserver(Observer o);
    void notifyObservers();
    void measurementsChanged();
    void setPrices(Map<String,Double> priceMap);
}


 class PriceData implements Subject {
    private ArrayList observers;
    PriceData priceData;
    private Map<String,Double> priceMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();

     PriceData() {
        observers = new ArrayList();
    }

public void registerObserver(Observer o) {
    observers.add(o);
}

public void removeObserver(Observer o) {
    int i = observers.indexOf(o);
    if (i >= 0) {
        observers.remove(i);
    }
}

public void notifyObservers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++) {
        Observer observer = (Observer)observers.get(i);
        observer.update(priceMap);
    }
}

public void measurementsChanged() {
    notifyObservers();
}

public void setPrices(Map<String,Double> priceMap) {
    this.priceMap = priceMap;
    measurementsChanged();
}


}







 class Test {

private static Map<String,Double> priceMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();
private static PriceData priceData = new PriceData();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // establish two portfolios as listeners for priceData.
    // for now, we assume that both portfolios contain the same
    // collection of investments.

    PricesDisplay firstPortfolio = 
        new PricesDisplay("00001", priceData);
    PricesDisplay secondPortfolio = 
            new PricesDisplay("00002", priceData);

    priceData.registerObserver(firstPortfolio);
    priceData.registerObserver(secondPortfolio);

    generateInitialPrices();
    updatePrices(.02);
    updatePrices(-.05);
    updatePrices(.06);
}

static void generateInitialPrices()
{
    priceMap.put("ASD", 42.50);
    priceMap.put("BDM", 52.50);
    priceMap.put("CAC", 22.20);
    priceMap.put("DFAS", 45.00);        
    priceData.setPrices(priceMap);
}

static void updatePrices(double changePercent)
{
    for( String key : priceMap.keySet())
    {
        double v = priceMap.get(key) * (1.0 + changePercent);
        priceMap.put(key, v);
    }
    priceData.setPrices(priceMap);
}
}
```

Comment: i registered the observers for each portfolio, but im still receiving an error when i run my program.

Answer (score 0):

setPrices should be :

```
public <map> void setPrices(Map<> priceMap) {
    this.priceMap = priceMap; // <-- missing line
    measurementsChanged();
}
```

Comment: not sure to understand your code logic :). But the PriceData#priceMap var was never set and thus always empty.